# ElasticSearch script query & geo distance query

Tags: elasticsearch

```
ElasticSearch version is 2.3.4
```

How to query geo_distance_query and script_query combination ?

I have an index, which has a lot of store information, there are location and distance fields.
Given a geo_point, the index based on the top of the query based on geo_distance_query this point to all store the distance, and calculated the distance should be less than the current store in the distance field value.

I think the script_query and geo_distance_query combination, do not know how to achieve.

Try the following code：

```
query: {
                bool: {
                    must: [
                        {
                            script: {
                                script: {
                                    inline: "doc['location'].arcDistance(" + _.lat + "," + _.lon + ") < doc['distance'].value"
                                    , lang: "painless"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
```

Results Elasticsearch error:

```
[illegal_argument_exception] script_lang not supported [painless]
```

Whether someone has encountered and solved this problem, using what method to implement the query ?

change code :

```
{
bool: {
    must: [
        {
            script: {
                script: {
                    inline: "doc['location'].arcDistance(" + _.lat + "," + _.lon + ") < doc['distance'].value"
                    , lang: "groovy"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

}

also error :

```
message: '[script_exception] failed to run inline script [doc[\'location\'].arcDistance(31.89484,120.287825) < doc[\'distance\'].value] using lang [groovy]',
```

detail image :

[image: code]
[image: result]

```
{
"error": {
    "root_cause": [{
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc[\'location\'].arcDistance(31.89484,120.287825) < 3000] using lang [groovy]"
    }],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query_fetch",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [{
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "business_stores_v1",
        "node": "Z_65eOYXT6u8aDf7mp2ZRg",
        "reason": {
            "type": "script_exception",
            "reason": "failed to run inline script [doc[\'location\'].arcDistance(31.89484,120.287825) < 3000] using lang [groovy]",
            "caused_by": {"type": "null_pointer_exception", "reason": null}
        }
    }]
}, "status": 500
```

}

Comment: The `painless` scripting language has been introduced in ES 5. What this error means is that you're running ES 2.x and you are reading the document for ES 5. If you're running ES 2.x, then use `groovy` instead of `painless`

Comment: @Val already update. also error .
I don't think he supports the way this query is compared with dynamic comparison .

Comment: What error do you get now? Surely a different one. Where do `_.lat` and `_.lon` come from?

Comment: @Val use Elasticsearch.js, "_"  is a param in nodeJS . just a object .And _.lat & _.lon from query params in url .

Comment: @Val just as `localhost:58128/v1/store?lat=31.89484&lon=120.287825` . 
I think there is no problem with the two parameters lat&lon . There is a problem with the distance parameter, which is derived from doc in es.

Comment: @Val So the distance between each column of data may be different, probably es does not support this dynamic line of data query .

Comment: Have you [enabled dynamic scripting](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.4/modules-scripting.html#enable-dynamic-scripting)?

Comment: in elasticsearch.yml , just note script.inline: true
script.indexed: true
script.file: true

Comment: Do you have more info about the error or just that single line?

Comment: @Val update . "arcDistance" , this method can be used in script query ?

Comment: @Val In 2.3.4,this method don't support?https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.2/modules-scripting-groovy.html#_doc_value_properties_and_methods but in this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.3/modules-scripting.html#_document_fields will see this method ....

Comment: The error you get means that one of the documents in your `business_stores_v1` index has a null `location` field and thus `arcDistance` fails. Do you confirm?

Comment: @Val thank you , one doc in es is null ...the "location" field is null ... thank you ... the code is runing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you're getting, i.e. `null_pointer_exception` is because one of the documents in your `business_stores_v1` index has a null `location` field and thus the formula fails

```
doc['location'].arcDistance(...)
               ^
               |
     null_pointer_exception here
```

Comment: Sorry, for a long time did not write java, has no intuitively aware of this error null_pointer_exception ...
thanks again